# Saving properties in a file with JAVA formatted

Tags: java, properties, formatting

Is there a way to save Properties in Java with some formatting using the Properties object? Like is there a way to introduce new lines between entries? Or comments before each key?

I know this can be easilly done with normal I/O but wondered if there's a way of doing it with the properties object.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The key to writing a comment between each set of properties is to store them in multiple `Properties` objects.

ie

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:/myconfig.property");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("com.app.port", "8080");
prop.put("com.app.ip", "127.0.0.1");

prop.store(fos, "A Test to write properties");
fos.flush();

Properties prop2 = new Properties();
prop2.put("com.app.another", "Hello World");
prop2.store(fos, "Where does this go?");
fos.flush();

fos.close();
```

This will produce an output such as

```
#A Test to write properties
#Fri Apr 08 15:28:26 ADT 2011
com.app.ip=127.0.0.1
com.app.port=8080
#Where does this go?
#Fri Apr 08 15:28:26 ADT 2011
com.app.another=Hello World
```

Comment: This will give me all the controll I need. Using different Properties objects I can add the coments I want and store them in the order I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have made a class that handles comments in properties.
Both general header comments and comments for individual properties.

Have a look at : [CommentedProperties JavaDoc](http://jhpropertiestyp.sourceforge.net/jhpropertiestyped/javadoc/dk/heick/properties/types/utils/CommentedProperties.html)

The jar file can be downloaded here : [Download jar file from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jhpropertiestyp/)

Comment: Please insert the main point of your answer here as an example, so in case of broken links an answer could still be found here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. How would the Properties element know what comments to write before each key?

You can include file-level comments when you [Properties.store( Writer, String ).](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) After that comment and a timestamp comment:

```
  Then every entry in this Properties table is written out, one per line.
  For each entry the key string is written, then an ASCII =, then the associated
  element string. For the key, all space characters are written with a 
  preceding \ character. For the element, leading space characters, but not 
  embedded or trailing space characters, are written with a preceding \ character. 
  The key and element characters #, !, =, and : are written with a preceding 
  backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded.
```

On the other hand, you *can* provide instructions on writing extra lines and comments in properties files -- using a Properties object as a source of data.

Answer (score 0):

The `Properties` object itself doesn't retain any details about the structure of how it was saved in the file. It just has a map of data, which in fact means it won't even necessary write them in the same order they were read. You'll have to use normal I/O to keep the formatting and make your desired changes.

Answer (score 0):

The class [CommentedProperties](http://jhpropertiestyp.sourceforge.net/jhpropertiestyped/javadoc/dk/heick/properties/types/utils/CommentedProperties.html)

Will parse the properties

```
 ## General comment line 1
 ## General comment line 2
 ##!General comment line 3, is ignored and not loaded
 ## General comment line 4


 # Property A comment line 1
 A=1

 # Property B comment line 1
 # Property B comment line 2
 B=2

 ! Property C comment line 1
 ! Property C comment line 2

 C=3
 D=4

 # Property E comment line 1
 ! Property E comment line 2  
 E=5

 # Property F comment line 1
 #!Property F comment line 2, is ignored and not loaded
 ! Property F comment line 3  
 F=5
```

The properties file comments is:

```
General comment line 1
General comment line 2
General comment line 4
```

So Property "A" comments is:

```
Property A comment line 1
```

So Property "B" comments is:

```
Property B comment line 1
Property B comment line 2
```

So Property "C"

```
Property C comment line 1
Property C comment line 2
```

So Property "D" comments is empty.

So Property "E" comments is:

```
Property E comment line 1
Property E comment line 2
```

So Property "F" comments is:

```
Property F comment line 1
Property F comment line 3
```

Comment: Great, but completely the opposite of what's being asked :P